# Angular Error TS2339 attempting to access/retrieve data from flask server

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to pull data from a flask database and present it on Angular. Getting an error in item/item.component.ts with error TS2339: Property 'itemdata' does not exist on type 'ItemComponent'

Accessing the flask endpoint shows an array of the data as expected, so I don't think that is related to the problem.

In itemdata.service.ts

```
...
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ItemdataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/item';

  getItem(): Observable<Item[]>{
  return this.http.get<Item[]>(this.API_URL);
  }

}
```

In item.component.ts

```
...
import {Item} from '../item';
import {ItemdataService} from '../itemdata.service';

...
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  item: Item[];

  constructor() { }

  getItem(): void{
    this.itemdata.getItem().subscribe(item=>this.item = item);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Expected successful compilation and for data to be retrieved successfully to be used for display.

Edit:
Now works with
    constructor(private itemdata: ItemdataService)

However data is not showing in template.
Data

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "First item"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Second item"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Third item"}]
```

item.component.html

```
<p>item list</p>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let x of item">
      <span>{{x.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<p>end of item list</p>
```

Data not showing on page. Instead, only the base page and "item list end of item list" is displayed.

Comment: You need to inject your service it seems..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor(private itemdata: ItemdataService)
```

Comment: This solved the issue, however it seems that I am now facing a new issue. On my component html page,
``<li *ngFor = "let x of item"><p>{{x.name}}</p></li>``
Nothing is being shown. It seems that it is not retrieving/storing the data properly.
The flask page endpoint with the data shows this
``[{"id": 1, "name": "First item"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Second item"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Third item"}]``

Comment: Can you add all of your template code to your question?
You can check here: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: Added, will also look through the link in the mean time. Thanks

Comment: I can see that you are not calling getItem() anywhere. You need to put the call into ngOnInit() which will call it when the component has been initialized.